# Parsing JSONObject and JSONArray on the same time

Tags: android, url, arrays, json

in loop for I get JSONArrays using this :

```
try{
    JSONArray json = jParserArray.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", param);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i("Message :", "the result is JSONObject"+e);
  }
```

but in some case the result is a JSONOBject, how can I verify what type of json I am getting?

NB: I am not getting the Log if the result is not JSONArray!!

this is my makeHttpRequest :

```
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONArray jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONArrayParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONArray makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONArray(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

thank you.

Comment: Make a try catch and on your catch use JSONObject instead

Comment: @PedroOliveira I try it, but I never get the error message as I mentioned above.

Comment: That means that the object is always an array. Why do you say that there are also objects?

Comment: because I get this error on logcat : Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value {"message error":"The requested record does not exist","error":107} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray .    this error generated by the object jParserArray

Comment: Share your makeHttpRequest method

Comment: Yes, your makeHttpRequest should throw Exception so you can catch it outside

Comment: get first index of your string and check that is equal to `{` or `[`, if it's `{` then your response is `JsonObject` , else your response is `JsonArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change your `makeHttpRequest` method's return type and handle it by checking its respose's instance:

```
public Object makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {


    //Your code at your question here (to your below comment) 

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    Object jObj = null;
    try {
        jObj = new JSONArray(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jObj;
}
```

And handle object:

```
Object json = jParserArray.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", param);
if(json instanceof JSONArray) {
    JSONArray jsonArr = (JSONArray) json ;
    // TODO: Handle json array
} else if (json  instanceof JSONObject) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) json ;
    // TODO: Handle json object
}
```